# Why is.factor() used in apply() and sapply() returns different values?

Tags: r, apply, sapply

My objective is to get a vector of boolean values to indicate whether or not each column in a data.frame is a factor, I used `is.factor()` in `sapply()` and `apply()` functions, and it seems like they return different value, and `apply()` returns the wrong value. Can someone tell me what causes the difference?

```
X <- data.frame(X1=c(1,2,3,4), ## numeric
                X2=factor(paste0("f",c(1:4))) ## factor)

sapply(X, is.factor)
## FALSE  TRUE 

apply(X, 2, is.factor)
## FALSE FALSE // apparently this is wrong, the second value is supposed to be TRUE.
```

Same thing happened to other functions like `class()`, `is.numeric()`.

Comment: `apply` changes `X` to be a matrix. It is advised to not use `apply` for data frames.

Comment: Look at output of `apply(X, 2, function(x) x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the reference of `apply`:

> Returns a vector or array or list of values obtained by applying a
> function to margins of **an array or matrix**.

Therefore, it converts your input object to a matrix (array) first which must have the same atomic data type. This means that your data get coerced to `character`, because `factor` is not an atomic vector type.

```
> as.matrix(X)
     X1  X2  
[1,] "1" "f1"
[2,] "2" "f2"
[3,] "3" "f3"
[4,] "4" "f4"
```